# Is SQL server's database a sql database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some clarification on databases and backend.

I am currently using microsoft sql server with a database connection. Does that mean, that the sql server uses an sql database? Or is it using a proprietary sql server database?

I don't understand the concept of database and it's associated platforms used. SQL server uses T-sql to connect with the database. But, can i use sqlite or mysql to connect with the same database?

Comment: _I don't understand the concept of database..._ This question is off-topic for SO. I am sure doing a proper research will answer your questions...

Comment: SQL is a query language specified by ISO/ANSI. Databases supporting this language can be called SQL databases. Unfortunately Microsoft named their product SQL Server, and this leads to confusion (intentionally?). Microsoft users tend to call SQL Server databases just SQL databases.

Comment: *"But, can i use sqlite or mysql to connect with the same database"* No. MySQL is a completely different application to SQL Server. SQLite is another completely different application, as is Oracle, MongoDB, etc, etc. They are all tools that are designed to do the same thing, but they are not the same thing. Much like a Ford Mondeo and a Honda Civic are both cars; but you couldn't replace the parts from a Civic with a Mondeo as they are completely different.

Comment: It would be not be called SQL server if it weren't an SQL Database. SQL is the general language (ANSI SQL) used by all SQL series databases, including MS Sql Server. It stands for Structured Query Language. You can't connect to it from SQLite or MySQL, but you can connect to it from say postgreSQL. That is something dependant on the backend you use.

Comment: If you create a C# program (front-end program) it can connect to a database (back-end DBMS). That can be a SQL Server database or a MySQL database for example.  There is no such thing as a "just a SQL table".  Or "just a SQL database".  They belong to some DBMS.  It's important to identify what program you are using to connect.  If it's Microsoft SQL Server- then that only manages SQL Server data.  If it's Visual Studio in a C# project, then you can write code to connect to various databases such as a SQL Server Database or a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications are often split into "front-end" and "back-end"; this is often an informal definition, but it might also refer to "client/server" architecture, or "n-tier" architecture.

The "front-end" is typically the user interface; the "backend" is everything else.

One of the key tasks of "backend" components is storing information.

There are lots of ways to do that; if you application domain is a good fit for relational data, it's common to use a relational database. The most common technology for relational databases (rdbms) is SQL, which is a standardized language for defining relational databases through data definition language (DDL), and retrieving and modifying data (DML).

There are many implementations of SQL - SQLite, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, MS SQL Server are all examples. Each implementation has its strengths and weaknesses; they all adhere to the SQL specification to some degree, and many have extensions beyond the SQL specification such as stored procedures, support for XML, free text search etc. Theoretically, it is possible to migrate between SQL implementations (e.g. from Oracle to MS SQL Server); in practice, this is usually very hard. To the best of my knowledge, there is no RDBMS which adheres 100% to the standard; it would probably not be hugely useful because the standard defines the language, rather than the implementation, and the implementation is what makes the database useful. For instance, the way the database implements indexes is a huge influence on performance.

T-SQL is a proprietary language, originally developed by Sybase (MS SQL Server was originally Sybase); it supports things like stored procedures etc. As far as I know, MS SQL Server is the only platform with support for T-SQL.

Your database connection specifies a few things: 
- which driver to use to connect to the database. The driver understands how to connect across the physical hardware (e.g. network), and how to convert your instructions into something the server understands. 
- the location of the server, and which particular database to use (one server can contain multiple databases)
- credentials to for authentication and authorization.